# I want to access my Session variable during my bean creation time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations, httpsession, spring-bean, session-scope

i want to use session variable during bean creation time in spring boot and my code is something like this.

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

String dbName;

@Bean(name = "jMaster")

@Autowired

public JdbcTemplate masterTemplate(@Qualifier("dsMaster") DataSource dsMaster) {

```
    this.dbName=// i want here to take value from session ;
    return new JdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Please write something like this: [enter link description here](https://github.com/TheBestSoftInTheWorld/SpringBoot_2_different_connections_to_the_database/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/springbootapp/configuration/persistence/context/DEVPersistenceContext.java)

```
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .username(env.getProperty("app.datasource.username"))
            .password(env.getProperty("app.datasource.password"))
            .url(env.getProperty("your URL to database"))
            .driverClassName(env.getProperty("app.datasource.driverClassName"))
            .build();
```